# How could these sirens move on land?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, merfolk, sea-creatures, animal-locomotion

The siren is an amphibious humanoid. They are mostly like humans apart from the limbs: Their arms are large and flipper-like, being used to swim underwater. Their leg is short, and they always have type 7 sirenomelia (where there is only one leg with a single femur). They evolved from a hopping humanoid with fused legs, which evolved from a typical walking humanoid

How would they move on land?

Comment: There's a light discrepancy in your question(s). Do you ask *if* they could "walk" effectively on land or *how* can they roam the land effectively (probably supposing they're not that good at walking in the first place)?

Comment: @Tortliena How they could go on land

Comment: @IchtysKing I've slightly altered the title to better match your thoughts ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest real mammalian counterpart from a creature like yours in terms of overall bodyplan (arm flippers, feet acting like fins) are seals and sea lions, and sea lions don't quite fit the bill since their 2 legs are still very much capable of acting like decently standard legs, unlike the legs of a seal which are essentially locked in a perpetual backwards position serving more like actual fins with basically no ability to move properly on land.

Therefore, your creature probably moves much like a seal, aka **bouncing** their way around.

[image]

A proper layer of fat might make this easier as well as allow for better insulation against colder temperatures.

Answer (score 3):

Flipper crawl. Not much extra needed for that sort of thing if their 'arms are large and flipper-like'

[image]